# Add overlapping plots to a pdf multipage

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf

I want to add overlapping plots to one subplot of a pdf page with the data: `x1`,`x2`,`y1`,`y2` etc.
So far this is my current state but it is not working clearly yet to display the subplots in the pdf:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

mp = PdfPages('multipage.pdf')

plt.grid()
plt.scatter(x1,y1)
plt.step([0,0],[-5,5], linewidth = 3,color ='orange')
plt.step([50,50],[45,55], linewidth = 3,color ='orange')
plt.step([100,100],[95,105], linewidth = 3,color ='orange')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)

plt.show()

plt.grid()
plt.scatter(x2,y2)
plt.step([0,0],[-5,5], linewidth = 3,color ='orange')
plt.step([50,50],[45,55], linewidth = 3,color ='orange')
plt.step([100,100],[95,105], linewidth = 3,color ='orange')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

fig = plt.figure()
ax2=fig.add_subplot(212)

plt.show()

mp.savefig(fig)

mp.close()
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want a page of this pdf to look like?

Comment: I have 7 plots and they should look like the stacking subplots in two directions [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) with going down with first plot blue, second orange, third green and so on

Comment: Is the approach in my answer what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but perhaps it will offer some help. This is an adaptation of [the example referenced in your comment](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html#stacking-subplots-in-two-directions) to use `PdfPages`:

```py
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axs[0, 0].plot(x, y)
axs[0, 1].plot(x, y, 'tab:orange')
axs[1, 0].plot(x, -y, 'tab:green')
axs[1, 1].plot(x, -y, 'tab:red')

mp = PdfPages('multipage.pdf')

mp.savefig(fig)
mp.close()
```